# Ruby YML file in Adhearsion - where should I load the file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

This code all exists in inbound_did context in dialplan.rb

```
host_config = YAML::load(File.open("config/hosts.yml")).to_hash
sip_hash = host_config["sip_hash"]
hostnames = host_config["hostnames"]
```

I'm trying to figure out if I should put YAML::load in dialplan.rb or somewhere else. I'd like to only load it once when adhearsion is started but I don't know how I could then access that config variable from the dialplan's scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to loads it only one then maybe constant will be OK for you?

```
class Dialplan
  HOST_CONFIG = YAML::load(File.open("config/hosts.yml")).to_hash

  def some_method
    sip_hash = HOST_CONFIG["sip_hash"]
    hostnames = HOST_CONFIG["hostnames"]
  end
end
```

then if you want to use it in another class then you can do something like this:

```
class Other
  def other_method
    sip_hash = Dialplan::HOST_CONFIG["sip_hash"]
    hostnames = Dialplan::HOST_CONFIG["hostnames"]
  end
end
```